# Adding new buckets to Tensorflow's seq2seq_model

Tags: tensorflow

I'm learning how to use Tensorflow seq2seq_model (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html). I'm having a problem where during training, the call to

`seq2seq_model.Seq2SeqModel(..., listOfBuckets, ...)`

takes forever since the buckets list it to large. If I try to have a smaller list by extending each bucket borders, then the call to `model.step(..)` takes forever.

My solution was to have a loop in which every iteration creates a new Seq2SeqModel and save the parameters in a file that I use to initialize the Seq2SeqModel in the next iteration. It looks something like that:

```
While cond:
   with tf.Session() as sess:
      model=seq2seq_model.Seq2SeqModel(..., listOfBuckets, ...)
      ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(training_dir)
      if ckpt and tf.gfile.Exists(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path):
           print("Reading model parameters from %s"   %ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
           model.saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

      doSomething()

      checkpoint_path = os.path.join(training_dir, "model.ckpt")
      model.saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path,global_step=model.global_step)

   listOfBuckets = someNewlistOfBuckets
```

But this seems to be a poor solution so my question is whether there is any way to add new buckets to the model (after it was already created) without creating it over and over again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, constructing buckets can take a while. There are now dynamic graphs in TensorFlow, so you can in principle construct a single graph for all buckets. But this is a large API change so we've not done it to seq2seq yet.

On the other hand, it's curious that using larger buckets slows your step down so much. Usually, the time of the step is linear in size, so using twice larger buckets only slows things down by about 2 times. Then, you can only use buckets for powers of 2 and get a very reasonable system. Did you try that? Maybe your step is slow for other reasons?